# PHP - SQL search between dd/mm/yyyy while having yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, search, between

I want to show data that from between date that I choose.

Already tried `SELECT * from myTable WHERE myDATE BETWEEN LIKE 'datefrom%' AND LIKE 'dateend%'`
and for CONVERT I still don't get it because haven't found one that have a full query about that.

As my title, my sql field is datetime type and with format 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'
while in php I have format dd/mm/yyyy

Please answer this only in PHP code and SQL query and in full mode.

Thank you :)

Comment: Keep trying, maybe check the MySQL documentation

Comment: Yeah, just learn basics of the basic basics of MySQL.

Comment: Reformat your data before sending it to the database.

Comment: @user2182349 do you have the link?

Comment: @EdCottrell what do you mean by reformat my data ? I don't know the exactly hh:mm:ss so only search with dd/mm/yyyyy, so using LIKE is the best possibility for me but that didn't work. so could you tell me how?

Comment: @blerrr - You'll need to use Google

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Comment: @blerrr I mean use PHP to convert the date you have in dd/mm/yyyy format to yyyy-mm-dd, then pass that result to the database. Much more efficient than doing it database side because you only have to do it it for two dates (start and end) instead of once per row in your result set.

Comment: I wonder why I got minus.. .......
@EdCottrell thanks for your explanation. I get it now :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do between `YYYY-MM-DD` and `YYYY-MM-DD` (excluding time) in MySQL but MySQL won't understand `dd/mm/yyyy` so you need to convert it to the proper format.

When you exclude the time, it interprets it at `00:00:00` so depending on your situation, you may want to do between `YYYY-MM-DD` and `YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59`

Note: PHP won't properly interpret `dd/mm/yyyy` either.  PHP date functions understand `mm/dd/yyyy` and `dd-mm-yyyy`.

Comment: This is the correct answer, especially the part about the times.

Answer (score 1):

As commenters have said, you will first have to convert your dd/mm/yyyy formatted date to something that MySQL prefers, which is YYYY-mm-dd H:i:s

So, how do you convert your date to MySQL friendly date? Do something like this:

```
<?php
$datefrom = '25/06/2015';
$dateend = '20/10/2015';

// create an array with dd, mm and yyyy
$splitFrom = explode('/', $datefrom);
$splitTo = explode('/', $dateend);

// mktime takes hour, minutes, seconds, month, day, year arguments
// create timestamp using mktime and pass it to date and format it to
// mysql friendly timestamp
$mysqlFrom = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',  mktime(0, 0, 0, $splitFrom[1], $splitFrom[0], $splitFrom[2]));
$mysqlTo = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',  mktime(0, 0, 0, $splitTo[1], $splitTo[0], $splitFrom[2]));

// echo sprintf("From %s and To %s", $mysqlFrom, $mysqlTo);

// this is where you would do your SQL statement and substitute $mysqlFrom and $mysqlTo dates

?>
```

Note that this is just a rudimentary example to show you how you can proceed with solving the problem yourself. As time passes, you will have to optimize this kind of code further.

Comment: Good, but you should use explode for this.  split has been deprecated for a while now.